# Using map to return an empty array instead of [0] zero

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have some working code that will take a string of words and return an array of the length of each word. For example:

```
let str = "hello world" returns [5, 5]
```

My issue is if str = "" (empty) it will return [0] instead of [] (empty array) which is what I'd like it to do. Does anyone have any ideas how I can alter my code to return this? Thank you!

```
const arr = str.split(' ');
return arr.map(words => words.length);
```

Comment: add if (str.length==0) return [0]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `filter` at the end.

```js
const str = "";
const arr = str.split(' ');
console.log(arr.map(words => words.length).filter(count => count != 0));
```

Answer (score 5):

You can return an empty array if the string is equal to `''` (empty string):

```js
function count(str) {
  return (str === '') ? [] : str.split(' ').map(({length}) => length);
}

console.log(count('hello world'));
console.log(count(''));
```